# How to auto-publish wordpress post to facebook groups

Tags: wordpress, facebook, rss, facebook-group

I would like to post an article to all of my groups where I am an administrator. Is there a plug in or some code to do this? Until now I have made it so that:

first --->had established a category e.g. groups
The second---> copy RSS feed address from my blog and paste it in RSS 2.0 feed (grafiti) application included.

Naturally this also runs, but then it gets up there via RSS ​​graffiti and not my application, as I usually do on my fan page or profile.
Thanks for all answers

Sorry I am from Germany and place answer easy!